# change a length format of a column in sas

Tags: sas, create-table

This is my code:

```
data want ; 
    input branch_id branch_name $ branch_specification $ bold_type $ bold_score $ ;
    DATALINES ;
    612 NATANYA masham_atirey  masham 1.15
    ;
run ;
```

the output for branch_specification is **masham_a**
I wish to longer the lenght.

Comment: To ensure a specific desired PDV use an `ATTRIB` statement to specify the metadata attributes of each variable before any of the variables are referenced in other statements, such as `INPUT`, `ARRAY`, the LHS of a computation, or use in a function invocation or routine call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `length` statement under your data statement.

```
length branch_specification $15.;
```

Just keep in mind that the length statement will put your manipulated variable at the front of your data set. You can change the order with a `retain` statement.

```
data want ; 
    retain branch_id branch_name branch_specification;
    length branch_specification $15.;
    input branch_id branch_name $ branch_specification $ bold_type $ bold_score $ ;
    DATALINES ;
    612 NATANYA masham_atirey  masham 1.15
    ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can input `branch_specification` using the `$15.` informat while using list input for the rest, e.g.

```
data want ; 
    input branch_id branch_name $ branch_specification :$15. bold_type $ bold_score $ ;
    DATALINES ;
612 NATANYA masham_atirey  masham 1.15
;
run ;
```

This way you don't need a separate length statement, and the variable order is unchanged.

Adding the `:` modifier prevents the input statement reading past the first delimiter (space by default) into the next variable in cases where `branch_specification` is less than 15 characters long.

Comment: Reading that one variable using FORMATTED input could cause problems if the value is shorter than 15 bytes.  It would be better to include the `:` modifier so that the variable is read using LIST MODE input, like the rest of the variables are.

Comment: When I create individual tables, the attribute data is OK (between 4 and 20 digits). When I use PROC SQL and UNION ALL, the attribute column length changes to a minimum of 4....